# Asynchronously populate DropDownItems on DropDownOpening

Tags: c#, winforms, asynchronous, drop-down-menu, async-await

I have a `ToolStripDropDownButton` on a `ToolStrip` and an asynchronous method which returns a list of items. To keep things simple, let's say this method looks like this:

```
private async Task<List<String>> getItems()
{
    await Task.Delay(100);
    return new List<String>() { "test 1", "test 2" };
}
```

What I want to achieve is this: As soon as the user clicks on the `ToolStripDropDownButton` I want to populate the drop down with the items returned by the asynchronous method.

The obvious place to populate the `DropDownItems` collection on demand is the `DropDownOpening` event handler.

I tried the following:

```
private async void toolStripDropDownButton1_DropDownOpening(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    toolStripDropDownButton1.DropDownItems.Clear();

    var items = await getItems();

    foreach (var item in items)
        toolStripDropDownButton1.DropDownItems.Add(item);
}
```

But no drop down is shown using this approach. I guess that after `await`, the drop down has already disappeared.

So my question is: How can I populate the drop down on demand with items returned from an asynchronous method, without blocking the GUI thread while waiting for the items?

### Edit

Note that blocking the GUI thread while waiting for the items, for example like shown below, causes a deadlock.

```
private void toolStripDropDownButton1_DropDownOpening(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    toolStripDropDownButton1.DropDownItems.Clear();

    var items = getItems().Result;
    foreach (var item in items)
        toolStripDropDownButton1.DropDownItems.Add(item);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure that's possible...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that using the `Click` event instead of the `DropDownOpening` event and then calling `ShowDropDown()` at the end works:

```
private async void toolStripDropDownButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    toolStripDropDownButton1.DropDownItems.Clear();

    var items = await getItems();

    toolStripDropDownButton1.DropDownItems.Clear();

    foreach (var item in items)
        toolStripDropDownButton1.DropDownItems.Add(item);

    toolStripDropDownButton1.ShowDropDown();
}
```

This produces some flickering but I can live with that.

Comment: Why `Clear` **before** and **after** the `await getItems` ?

Answer (score 0):

You probably should be populating the list of items to show at another point *prior* to the user clicking the drop down. You have to see what is the best time for your application when your list is valid.

I'd say when the form is loaded or initialized might be a couple of better options. Then using `async` will mean that your GUI remains responsive while the items are being retrieved in the background.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. I was also thinking about this workaround. But the items come from a remote system and I have no idea when this list changes. I also don't want to periodically poll the remote system for the items. So it really should happen on demand when needed.